# Jest: Spy on other function in module being tested

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to test a module using jest. In the module, I have a function which works as a kind of front to two other functions, and delegates to them based on its parameter. I'm trying to figure out if these functions have indeed been called.

I have tried using a spy function, but it is never called. Instead, the actual function is called, bypassing my spy.

All examples I have found with mocking and spies involve mocking and spying on another module than the one being tested, but in this case I am trying to spy on a function from the module being tested. Is this even possible? Is there a better way to do this?

Example code:

```js
// funcs.js

const decide = obj => {
  if (obj.a !== undefined) {
    return funcA(obj);
  } else {
    return funcB(obj);
  }
};

const funcA = obj => obj.a;
const funcB = obj => obj.b;

export { decide, funcA, funcB };
```

```js
// funcs.test.js

import * as fns from "./funcs";

describe("decide", () => {
  it("should delegate to 'funcA' when the parameter has an 'a' property", () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(fns, "funcA");
    fns.decide({ a: "Cake" });
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // Error! Number of calls: 0
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to spy or mock a function that is called in the same ES module it is defined.

This is possible for CommonJS modules but only if functions are consistently referred as methods:

```
exports.decide = obj => {
  ...
  exports.funcA(obj);
  ...
};

exports.funcA = obj => obj.a;
```

It's possible to adopt this recipe to ES modules but this discards their benefits:

```
const exports = {};
export default exports;

// same as CommonJS
```

`funcA` and `funcB` should be either moved to separate module for testability purposes and be spied or mocked with `jest.mock`, or all of them should be tested as a single unit.